# How to disable/reduce cache from magento admin notification?

Tags: php, magento, caching, admin

I created a module a few minutes ago to pull information from a RSS feed and display it in the admin panel's notification inbox and toolbar that's right below the admin menu.

This works perfectly, but unfortunately it doesn't load new messages when I refresh. I have to flush Magento's cache and then refresh for it to load the new messages.

I would like to disable cache for the notifications module/block, so all new messages can be loaded each time the page is loaded.

I tried this line of code but it didn't seem to work:

```
<reference name="notification_toolbar">
    <action method="setCacheLifetime"><s>0</s></action>
</reference>
```

Can someone please advise me on how to disable the cache from this module/block.

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking through some codes i realize it has a update frequency timer, so i looked in the system section of the admin panel and found a update frequency selector under **configuration** => **system** => **notification**. Unfortunately the least time it had is **1 hour**.

I went through the mage folders and found the following that provides the times.

> Mage/Adminhtml/Model/System/Config/Source/Notification/Frequency.php

```
class Mage_Adminhtml_Model_System_Config_Source_Notification_Frequency
{
    public function toOptionArray()
    {
        return array(
            1   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('1 Hour'),
            2   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('2 Hours'),
            6   => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('6 Hours'),
            12  => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('12 Hours'),
            24  => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('24 Hours')
        );
    }
}
```

I then added the follow code and ran some tests, which worked!

```
0 => Mage::helper('adminhtml')->__('0 Minute'),
```

Not sure if i did it correctly, but it does exactly what i need it to.
i then override this with my module to complete it.

Hope it helps others!